# Apache Camel does not download files from external FTP

Tags: maven, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I'm running a standalone camel route.
Running my Main.class in Eclipse->Run-As->Java Application it works fine. The file is consumed and all the route works.

When i do git-clone in my ec2 machine and perform `mvn package -> mvn exec:java` of the same project it runs normally but only ping the FTP endpoint, not downloading the file.

I checked all the jars in my dependency-jars file(in my ec2) and they are the same as in the Eclipse maven-dependencies(locally)

my pom looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <url>myUrl</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <!-- common -->
        <slf4j.version>1.7.10</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <camel.version>2.15.2</camel.version>
        <commons.lang3.version>3.4</commons.lang3.version>
        <commons.logging.version>1.2</commons.logging.version>
        <commons.io.version>2.4</commons.io.version>
        <joda.time.version>2.6</joda.time.version>
        <jackson.version>2.3.0</jackson.version>
        <jackson.xml.databind.version>0.6.2</jackson.xml.databind.version>
        <aspectjweaver.version>1.6.0</aspectjweaver.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
            <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
            <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
            <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
            <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
<!--    <dependency> -->
<!--    <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId> -->
<!--    <artifactId>transactions-hibernate4</artifactId> -->
<!--    <version>4.0.0M4</version> -->
<!-- </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- FTP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ftpserver/ftpserver-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ftpserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>ftpserver-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- bindy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-bindy</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda.time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.10.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1103-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>


         <!-- logging -->

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  /logging -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache-extras.camel-extra</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-xstream</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-xml-databind</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20151123</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectjweaver.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.logging.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.io.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.mina/mina-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
</dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- allows the route to be ran via 'mvn camel:run' -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                  <mainClass>main.MainApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- to generate the MANIFEST-FILE of the bundle -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>

                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>main.MainApp</mainClass>
                            <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                                      ${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/
                                </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
              </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>main.MainApp</mainClass>
                    <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <key>spring.profiles.active</key>
                            <value>testing</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <arguments />
                </configuration>


    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Also posted on Camel user forum: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Apache-Camel-connect-but-does-not-download-files-from-external-FTP-tp5783051.html

Comment: Could this be a permission issue? Can you turn DEBUG on and see what happens in the logs? You could post them here for us to have a look.

Comment: The answer is posted on the Camel user forum.